# Python 34 over windows NULLED output file

Tags: python, windows, file, python-3.x

I have a Python script that runs on windows what it does is create out put test files. Every so often one of the files it creats is full NULL bytes with correct size as if some one memset file to 0.
I Attached the code that creates file:

```
 def write_regression_file(self, regression_tests, excel_name, work_sheet_names):

    tcl_base_filename = self.output_file_base_name if self.output_file_base_name !="" else '{}RegressionTests'.format(self.protocol) 
    regression_test_file =  '{}{}_{}.tcl'.format(self.gen_path, tcl_base_filename.replace('Tm',''), excel_name)
    full_regresion_test_file = regression_test_file.replace('_'+excel_name, '')
    tcl_gen_path = '${}GeneratedPath/'.format(self.protocol.lower())
    #
    # Create per Excel regression Tcl test file
    with open(regression_test_file, 'a') as regression_file:
        #
        # write sources for excel
        for ws_name in work_sheet_names:
            sourceline = 'source {}{}.tcl\n'.format(tcl_gen_path, ws_name.replace(' ', '_'))
            regression_file.write(sourceline)
        header  = '\t##########################################################\n'
        header += '\t# Regression Tests for Excel file {}\n'.format(excel_name)
        header += '\t##########################################################\n'
        regression_file.write(header)
        #
        # write tests
        for group, test_list in regression_tests.items():
            test_name            = 'test' + excel_name.replace(' ', '_') + '_' + group
            string_to_write      = '\n proc {} {{}} {{\n\t'.format(test_name)
            string_to_write     += '\n\t'.join(test_list)
            string_to_write     += '\n }'
            regression_file.write(string_to_write)
        regression_file.write('\n\n\n\n\n\n')
    #
    # Source per Excel regression file in full regression test file
    all_file_regressions_names = glob.glob(self.gen_path + '*RegressionTests_*.*')
    with open(full_regresion_test_file, 'w') as full_reg_file:
        for regression_fullpath in all_file_regressions_names:
            source_line = 'source ${}GeneratedPath/{}\n'.format(self.protocol.lower(), ntpath.basename(regression_fullpath))
            full_reg_file.write(source_line)
```

The error happened on the second open (one file "full_regresion_test_file")
Instead of it containing the expected 'source ...' string the file is just full of b'x\00' the size is the correct size though.

Comment: Do you ever close your files?

Comment: I don't need to using "with open()" should deal with that

Comment: Indeed – apologies! "It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes [..]" ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)).